# How to configure Django settings for different environments in a modular way?

Tags: python, django, wsgi, django-settings

I have already searched on the web on this doubt, but they don't really seem to apply to my case.

I have 3 different config files - Dev, Staging, Prod (of course)

I want to modularize settings properly without repetition. So, I have made  base_settings.py and I am importing it to dev_settings.py, stg_settings.py etc.

**Problem - How to invoke the scripts on each env properly with minimal changes?**

Right now, I'm doing this (taking dev env as an example)-

**python manage.py runserver --settings=core.dev_settings**

This works so far, but I am not convinced on how good workaround is this.
Because wsgi.py and a couple of other services have -

**os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'core.settings')**

I am looking to do something without changing the config files of other services. Thank you everyone in advance.

PS - I've tried to be as clear as possible, but please excuse me if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` in environment variables to your desired config file.

That won't make you to change any of other services config files, and you don't even need to change django settings files.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response! I've a small doubt as an extension to this. If I run gunicorn instead of managy.py, how to specify the appropriate settings file?

Comment: @NirlenduSaha yes, if you run it with gunicorn, then it will use your .wsgi file, and then it will search in `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable, and if it's not present it will set `core.settings` for your example.

Comment: I tried your approach. Did  export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='core.settings.local'
 echo $$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE

Comment: Did that in makefile, but oddly, it is not set there. But if I do that in cmd separately, there's no problem. Do you know how/why this happens? I am using a mac, just in case.

Comment: @NirlenduSaha Be sure that this environment variable should be set when you restart your server. It's the same approach with setting `SECRET_KEY`, you should get that value from environment. Basically you can use virtualenvwrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Django Configurations](https://django-configurations.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) package.

Comment: Wow. This looks sweet, might be just what I needed. I will check this module. Thanks for the response! :)